# ANT migration - NamedFilter

Tags: ant

I'm trying to migrate a few adjustments to a Custom Object from sandbox to prod.  One is a new "Named Filter" or Lookup Filter to another custom object.  I guess I have two questions.

1) I'm getting the message "Entity of Type 'NamedFilter' named 'User Group Request_CM Folder Group' cannot be found" - no matter how I structure the XML or what "names" I use.  The XML I'm trying is:

User Group Request_CM Folder Group
        NamedFilter
    
    28.0

And User_Group_Request__c and CM_Folder_Group__c are 2 custom objects.

The  value comes from an ANT retrieval - I've tried prefixing this name with both objects, but no luck.....

Sorry to ask, but what am I doing incorrectly?  How should this XML be structured to get NamedFilter correct?

2) And more generally, when I need to make such a small change to an existing Custom Object, would it be better to just migrate the whole object over again?  Would that create a duplicate object?  Does the ANT migration process just post the differences when an existing  Custom Object is migrated?

I'm a bit confused about the above.  Especially since there's a CustomField migration type that WILL create a new field on an existing object without migrating the complete object.  Is it safe to just migrate the entire object every time there's a change?  Presumably there would be no loss of data ?

Sorry if these are obvious questions - for the life of me I don't see the answers this morning...

thanks